# Retrieving parent url parameters from ajax call?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, tastypie

say I have a view at

```
url(regex=r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'...)
```

and in the template of that view I have an ajax post to an api (via tastypie) at

```
url(regex=r'^post/$'...)
```

Is there a way in the tastypie api resource functions to pull out the url slug of the parent view?

Note: I prefer a django kind of way, not something like passing in document.URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is stateless. Meaning that each request is processed independently of other requests. Therefore when the ajax call is made, it is completely independent of the parent page. As a matter of fact, it does not even have to be an ajax call from the parent page. You can just separately make the ajax call outside of the parent page.

The only solution is to manually pass something to the ajax call. You can pass the parent page URL manually (using JS) to the ajax call. Alternatively when the parent page is being rendered, you can store the page URL in the session. Then in an ajax call, you can retrieve that URL and use it as you like. I would however recommend the first method because the other one is more error-prone and possibly not as secure.